# undesirable/buggy change in behavior of Limit in Mma 11.2?

Tags: core-language

The behavior of `Limit` changed in Mma 11.2, and I think it is in some ways undesirable or possibly buggy.  Consider

```
Limit[Sin[t Pi], t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> Element[t, Integers]]
```

This used to (11.1) produce a correct result and no longer does (11.3).  Is this intentional or a bug?  (More understandable but still slightly disappointing is that `Limit` no longer returns limiting sets of values.  E.g., removing the assumptions from the above expression, it used to return an interval, while it now returns the less informative `Indeterminate`.)

I am aware than I can change to `DiscreteLimit`, which is a nice addition, or use other tricks (e.g., `Sum` of differences).

Comment: v11.2 on my Mac also evaluates to `0` so although `DiscreteLimit` was introduced with v11.2, the change observed was not fully implemented until v11.3

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation told me, the interval arithmetic can be restored with

```
Limit[Sin[x Pi], x -> ∞, Method -> {"AllowIndeterminateOutput" -> False}]
```

> Interval[{-1, 1}]

I guess that this change was made for performance reasons, speeding up `Limit` with the default options.

Comment: While this is useful for my subsidiary question, it does not address my main question.  Is it a bug to apparently ignore the `Assumptions`?

Comment: Well, I know. There a pros and cons for calling that a bug. I am rather indifferent in that matter.

Comment: What are the cons?  Is there a motivation in the changes for the new behavior, which unlike the old behavior fails to appropriately use this assumption?  (I'm not seeing it.)  Just to be clear, it fails even if you change the `Method` as above.

Comment: I submitted a report and received this answer: "The assumptions in `Limit` and related functions are only supposed to apply to parameters and not the limit variable."